# Counting even number haskell with list comprehension?

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I implemented a function that can count a list of numbers and produces how many even numbers in the list, I implemented using recursion, but I need this time with list comprehension.
I did try using list comprehension, but once I executed the function its just hang and it gives me nothing. Here is my code:

```
countEven :: (Integral t, Num a) => [t] -> a
countEven [] = 0
countEven  (x:xs)
    | ev == True    = 1 + (countEven xs )
    | otherwise     = countEven xs
    where ev    = even x
```

This is my attempt using list comprehension :

```
evenList :: (Integral t, Num a) => [t] -> a
evenList xs =  countEven [x | x <- [1..]]
```

Comment: I did search it in this site, I only found the same function with recursion but not with list comprehension implementation.

Comment: `[1..]` contains an infinite number of even numbers - that's why `countEven` hangs.

Comment: You are right my bad:( i just figerd it out I ma a new in Haskell, any thought what to put instead? i tried to put [1..n] but it does not work?

Comment: Your `countEven` function looks fine. What do you want the `evenList` function to do?

Comment: Never use `x == True`, use just `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions can be used to produce other lists, but not counts. Thus, you need to combine a list comprehension with something else, e.g.

```
countEvens :: [Int] -> Int
countEvens l = length [ x | x <- l, even x ]
```

Here, the list comprehension just produces a sublist with all the even numbers, and `length` finishes the job.

Comment: Thanks its so simple but I do not know why I complicated it lol